# Unable to upload XLSX files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, pyrocms

This is a common issue from what I have found.

A discussion is also found here 
https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/18587

As suggested on many sites I needed to add mime types to the xls and xlsx. So I below is a snippet of my **xlsx** mime type which I amended however Pyro is still not allowing me to upload the file.

```
'xlsx'  =>array('application/x-msexcel', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel'),
```

It does not allow me to upload through the files module or through a custom module.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...i think it will helps you

```
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip')
```